# Atom's Git integration not working: merge conflict markers not highlighting

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, atom-editor

I'm using Github desktop for a Unity project that I'm working on with some class mates. I've been using Atom to merge conflicts because it provides a helpful GUI that highlights each conflict, especially because I am a total beginner at using git. However, for some reason Atom is no longer highlighting the marked areas in my code (pictured here):

[conflict markers not highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8i8r.png)

I understand I could manually go to each marker and resolve it but in the cases of a scene conflict in Unity, some files are thousands of lines long and you can imagine how tedious it would be. I haven't been able to find similar problems with Atom online and I'm not well versed enough in git to figure it out myself. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have the same problem, it stopped work for me recently

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the project folder to Atom? "File > Add Project Folder..."

That might give reference to the .git folder, anyhow it worked for me :)

Comment: What the version of Atom you are using?

Comment: @rob_the_dev for me also it have worked. I am using 1.44.0 version. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading from 1.43 to 1.42 seems to have resolved this issue. I would suggest filing a bug report to Atom.
https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-bugs